# Close mobile menu when clicked on anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to close the mobile menu (hamburger) when title in the menu is clicked. The title is set as anchor.

I have tried this code but the menu does not pop out anymore.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1344').on('click', function() {
    $('#nm-mobile-menu-button').trigger('click'); });
});
```

Website [Nilmore](https://nilmore.com)

Theme Savoy

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You task is simple. You've could debug it yourself by using Developer Tools.

- your menu (*on open*) gets the class `.mobile-menu-open`
- therefore you need to remove that class on any menu item click

i.e:

```
const $menu = $("#nm-mobile-menu");
const $menu_items = $menu.find(".menu-item");

$menu_items.on("click", function(ev) {
  // ev.preventDefault(); // uncomment to prevent browser scroll-to Anchor
  $menu.removeClass("mobile-menu-open");
});
```

.mobile-menu-open #nm-mobile-menu

Comment: Thank you for your help. For some reason I had to change `$menu_items.on` to `$menu_items.bind` . Not sure why but after that it worked.

Comment: @JakubHavrlant from jQuery 3.* the .bind method is deprecated. Use the `.on()` method instead.